# how to extract all hh:mm:ss from array of object containing datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, hour

I have zz1 array with
type: Array of object;
Size: (2,1);
Value: ndarray object of numpy module

zz1 contains: 2017-02-01 23:59:51.705317, 2017-02-01 23:59:51.720942

```
zz1[0,].hour
```

gives only first hour. While,

```
zz1[0:2,].hour
```

throws error!! How to get all the hours together in one array?

Comment: In general, are you restricted to working with numpy? Specifically, do you want to extract the full time (H:M:S)? What should be the output data type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get a list with the value you need. You also need to cast the result to `np.array`, maintaining the overall structure.

```
np.array([el.hour for el in zz1])
```

Comment: np.array([el.hour for el in zz1]) worked.

Thank you so much.

BTW what is "el"?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe that Deusy94 is using 'el' as the parameter to represent an arbitrary element in the list comprehension expression.